# Why does sbt keep telling me to add -deprecation to scalacOptions when it's already?

Tags: scala, sbt

Here below is my multi-project structure:

```
myApp
  + build.sbt
  + sub-prj-1
      + build.sbt
  + sub-prj-2
      + build.sbt
  + project
      + Build.scala
```

I use to define common settings in `project/Build.scala` like this:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val defaultScalacOptions = Seq(
    "-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature", "-language:reflectiveCalls", "-language:implicitConversions",
    "-language:postfixOps", "-language:dynamics", "-language:higherKinds", "-language:existentials",
    "-language:experimental.macros", "-encoding", "UTF-8", "-Xmax-classfile-name", "140")

  val defaultResolvers = Seq(
    "Typesafe releases repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
  )

  val defaultSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
    scalacOptions ++= defaultScalacOptions,
    resolvers ++= defaultResolvers
  )
}
```

... and then I reference these common settings in each `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "myapp"

organization := "Test, Inc."

version := "1.0"

ApplicationBuild.defaultSettings // it looks like common settings defined in
                                 // project/Build.scala are not read...

scalacOptions += "-feature"      // already defined in ApplicationBuild.defaultSettings...
                                 // but if I don't define it here, it doesn't work

lazy val `sub-prj-1` = project.in(file("sub-prj-1"))

lazy val `sub-prj-2` = project.in(file("sub-prj-2"))

lazy val brix = project.in(file(".")).settings(
  publishArtifact := false
).aggregate(
  `sub-prj-1`,
  `sub-prj-2`
)
```

For example, `scalacOptions += "-feature"` is already defined in `Build.scala`... but if I don't define it in `build.sbt` I always get the following warning:

```
[warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
```

Any idea? Am I missing something? This problem first appeared after I installed sbt 0.13.5.

**EDIT**

Here's the content of `scalacOptions`:

```
[info] sub-prj-1/*:scalacOptions
[info]  List(-unchecked, -deprecation, -feature, -language:reflectiveCalls, -language:implicitConversions, -language:postfixOps, -language:dynamics, -language:higherKinds, -language:existentials, -language:experimental.macros, -encoding, UTF-8, -Xmax-classfile-name, 140)
[info] sub-prj-2/*:scalacOptions
[info]  List(-unchecked, -deprecation, -feature, -language:reflectiveCalls, -language:implicitConversions, -language:postfixOps, -language:dynamics, -language:higherKinds, -language:existentials, -language:experimental.macros, -encoding, UTF-8, -Xmax-classfile-name, 140)
[info] myapp/*:scalacOptions
[info]  List(-unchecked, -deprecation, -feature, -language:reflectiveCalls, -language:implicitConversions, -language:postfixOps, -language:dynamics, -language:higherKinds, -language:existentials, -language:experimental.macros, -encoding, UTF-8, -Xmax-classfile-name, 140)
```

Comment: Can you do `show scalacOptions` in sbt console and add the output to the question?

Comment: Just on time when I responded :) I think I may have helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only guess (and counting on additional information to be corrected when mistaken), but the `warn` messages are from the build project (under `project`) not yours.

I'm on sbt 0.13.6-SNAPSHOT (built from the sources today) so your mileage may vary.

```
➜  myApp  xsbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/project/}myapp-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[info] Set current project to brix (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/)
```

When I tried to reproduce your case, I ended up with the messages coming for the build definition under `project`:

```
[warn] there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
```

Are they what you want to get rid of? If so, read on. Else add additional information to your question. Thanks.

For [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive), what's beneath `project` is another build definition (and so on).

In order to get rid of the messages, you should follow their advice and add `-deprecation` to the build definition of the corresponding project. Add the following to **project/build.sbt**:

```
scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

With this, `reload` and the mystery becomes uncovered.

```
➜  myApp  xsbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] /Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/project/Build.scala:15: value defaultSettings in object Defaults is deprecated: 0.13.2
[warn]   val defaultSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
[warn]                                  ^
[warn] one warning found
[info] Set current project to brix (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/common-settings/myApp/)
>
```

[As sbt.Defaults says](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L908):

```
@deprecated("0.13.2", "Default settings split into `coreDefaultSettings` and IvyModule/JvmModule plugins.")
```

To fix this, one should read the article [Preview of upcoming sbt 1.0 features: Read about the new plugins](http://typesafe.com/blog/preview-of-upcoming-sbt-10-features-read-about-the-new-plugins).

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive answer ;-)